# How to express a string literal containing double quotes without escape characters?

Tags: c#

Is there a C# syntax with which I can express strings containing double quotes without having to escape them? I frequently copy and paste strings between C# source code to other apps, and it's frustrating to keep adding and removing backslashes.

Eg. presently for the following string (simple example)

> "No," he said.

I write in C# `"\"No,\" he said."`

But I'd rather write something like Python `'"No," he said.'`, or Ruby `%q{"No," he said.}`, so I can copy and paste the contents verbatim to other apps.

Comment: I don't think it's possible (the only alternative being using a verbatim string with double quotes, in your case `@"""No"", he said"`).

Comment: you can use different [quotation marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs), for example: `"“No,” he said"`

Comment: Vote for C# feature request for `"""` raw string literals similar to Python https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4304

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I frequently copy and paste strings between C# source code to other apps, and it's frustrating to keep adding and removing backslashes.

Then it sounds like you probably shouldn't have the strings within source code.

Instead, create text files which are embedded in your assembly, and load them dynamically... or create resource files so you can look up strings by key.

There's no form of string literal in C# which would allow you to express a double-quote as *just* a single double-quote character in source code.

Answer (score 5):

You could try this but you're still effectively escaping:

```
string s = @"""No,"" he said.";
```

Answer (score 2):

Update 2022: C# 11 in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2 (or later) supports raw string literals between `"""` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#raw-string-literals

> Raw string literals are a new format for string literals. Raw string literals can contain arbitrary text, including whitespace, new lines, embedded quotes, and other special characters without requiring escape sequences. A raw string literal starts with at least three double-quote (""") characters. It ends with the same number of double-quote characters. Typically, a raw string literal uses three double quotes on a single line to start the string, and three double quotes on a separate line to end the string. The newlines following the opening quote and preceding the closing quote aren't included in the final content:

Example (note that StackOverflow doesn't yet highlight correctly)

```cs
string longMessage = """
    This is a long message.
    It has several lines.
        Some are indented
                more than others.
    Some should start at the first column.
    Some have "quoted text" in them.
    """;
```